# pentaho create to many hibernate connection

Tags: mysql, pentaho

I set maxactive=20, but when I execute show processlist I show over 30 connection like this:

```
109051 | root | localhost:33203     | hibernate   | Sleep   |    4 |       | N
```

This is my setting:

mysql5.hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</property><property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</property>
<property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate</property>
<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>
<property name="connection.username">user</property>
<property name="connection.password">password</property>
<property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
<property name="show_sql">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.jdbc.use_streams_for_binary">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property><property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">75</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout">true</property>
```

context.xml

```
<Context path="/pentaho" docbase="webapps/pentaho/">
<Resource name="jdbc/Hibernate" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" username="user" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hibernate" validationQuery="select 1"/>
<Resource name="jdbc/Quartz" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" factory="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory" maxActive="20" maxIdle="5" maxWait="10000" username="user" password="password" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quartz" validationQuery="select 1"/>
</Context>
```

How can I fix for this problem ?
Best Regard

Comment: are you sure you do not have multiple instances of your app running ?

Comment: maybe, because I am working with BI suite which is open source, so I just use config without no change source code and I check there is no other app run.

Answer (score 1):

> hibernate.c3p0.max_size This is the maximum number of connections in
>   the pool. An exception is thrown at runtime if this number is
>   exhausted.

And you have :

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">75</property>
```

so change it to :

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">20</property>
```